# Woocommerce account billing/shipping city to select in the account settings

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How to change account billing/shipping fields to select? I found how to do that for checkout page but i can't find any info how to do that for user
http://my-fake-domain.example.com/my-account/edit-address/billing/

For checkout page:

```
function jeroen_sormani_change_city_to_dropdown( $fields ) {

  $city_args = wp_parse_args( array(
    'type' => 'select',
    'options' => array(
      'amsterdam' => 'Monaco',
      'rotterdam' => 'Beausoleil',
      'den-haag'  => 'Cap d’Ail'
    ),
    'input_class' => array(
      'wc-enhanced-select',
    )
  ), $fields['shipping']['shipping_city'] );

  $fields['shipping']['shipping_city'] = $city_args;
  $fields['billing']['billing_city'] = $city_args; // Also change for billing field

  wc_enqueue_js( "
    jQuery( ':input.wc-enhanced-select' ).filter( ':not(.enhanced)' ).each( function() {
        var select2_args = { minimumResultsForSearch: 5 };
        jQuery( this ).select2( select2_args ).addClass( 'enhanced' );
    });" );

  return $fields;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'jeroen_sormani_change_city_to_dropdown' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved by

```
add_filter('woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'jeroen_sormani_change_city_to_dropdown');
```